# hibernate - generated SQL contains more fields than I update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Consider the following scenario:

```
class User {
  Long id;
  BigDecimal balance;
  BigDecimal rating;

  @ManyToOne
  Team team;
}

class Team {
  Long id;
  BigDecimal rating;
}
```

Then in code I have the following:

```
@Transactional
void updateBalance(...) {
   user.addBalance(balance);                  // add balance
   increaseUserRating(user, balance);         // update rating by an algorithm
   increaseTeamRating(user.getTeam(), balance);// update team rating by an algorithm
}
```

So, I expect the following SQL to be executed:

```sql
update users set balance = $1, rating = $2 where id = $3;
-- update teams as well
```

But I get:

```sql
update users set balance = $1, rating = $2, team_id = $3; -- why's the team updated huh?
```

Is this a normal behaviour? I suspect that `team_id` is updated to guarantee data consistency since we update team row too. Am I correct?

Comment: @M.Deinum, please, see the update. `login` field is unchanged.

Comment: The team is dirty so gets an update (you are doing something which increases the team rating), hibernate then thinks, due to the dirty team, it needs to update that field also. Interesting btw as historically all fields where updated (but might have changed with JPA, not sure).

Comment: Are these the complete SQL statements? No WHERE clause?

Comment: @ThomasStets, thanks for pointing. For sure there ARE `where` clauses.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I looked through logs properly, and you're right - simply all fields are updated. Could you convert your comment to an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: I'm not understand your problem clearly. Assume your are talking about cascade. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html

Answer (score 0):

When you will try to change any value of a domain that is in a relation with some other domain, like your case
`Many Users to a Team Unidirectional with User as the Relation Holder`. Here you will have `Team as an object for every User domain` So when you update the User object it will try to update each field of the domain `User` thus it will also try to update the `Team` object associated with the User.

Also if you try to update a `Team` object then the User objects will not be updated.